# Given a python object, how can we get a complete list of everything that object has direct handles/references to?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, getattr, getattribute

Suppose we are handed a python object. We have no earthly idea where it came from, or what it contains. By calling various functions on the object, how can we coax out a definitive list of names for data the object has references to?

I am only interested in data accessible through python APIs. If an object has some low-level memory buffer which has no corresponding interface in python, then I don't need access to that; but I **do** want to know how to get access to **every** python interface an object does have.

My question is similar to asking how can we get a the list of all of a python object's attributes. However, there are some caveats.

I do not want any overloaded `__getattribute__` (dot-operator) methods getting in the way. We can bypass any overloaded dot-operators by calling, `object.__getattribute__(obj, 'x')`. However, calls to `object.__getattribute__` require that we already have access to the names of the attributes we care about. For the usage I envision, we have no idea where the object came from or what the names of its attributes might be. We simply don't know which strings to pass into `obj.__getattribute__`

python's `dir()` method is a step in the right direction, but it is not exactly what we are looking for. `dir` will return class methods. However, a python object has no direct references to the class methods. Usually, the object will have a reference to the class which it is instantiated from (through `__bases__`). Then, the class is what actually has references to the methods. Class methods are attributes of the class, and not attributes of an instance/object. Thus, `dir(obj)` returns things which aren't directly owned by `obj`. Another way to view it is that I am seeking single-layer access, not multi-layer access. If a python object (dictionary key) points to another dictionary, which points to another dictionary, and so on, I only want access to the very first dictionary which the name/label refers to. `dir` goes and gets the names of things which the object does not have a direct pointer to.

At first I thought that every python object had a '**dict**', attribute, and '**dict**' was a definitive list of all names the object encapsulated. However, this isn't so. Also, `vars(obj)` is unacceptable, since it will throw an error for many python objects, including instances of some of the built-in classes. I am looking for a solution which would tell us a little about ANY python object; not work for some and raise an exception for others.

Comment: you probably want to try `vars(obj)` then catch a type-error, then try something like `{x:getattr(a, x) for x in a.__slots__}`, in which case, you will catch an attribute error, and then the object doesn't have any direct references to other objects.

Comment: `gc.get_referents()` is probably the most general solution, but even that doesn't work on all types.  You're never going to get 100% coverage no matter what you do, and you aren't going to get *anywhere* unless you're willing to use `try`/`except` to attempt things that WILL throw exceptions on some objects.